# Raspberry PI powered via USB A in car when using ODB2 Port

Tags: raspberry-pi, automotive

I'm running a Rasberry PI 4 in my car to read values from the ODB2 Port.

Below is the diagram of my setup.

[image]

The PI is powered via the Cigarette Port using a 12v to USB charger that has an On/Off button attached.

My problem is that when USB charger is turned off the Raspberry PI still turns on boots up when I turn the car on but I get the low power warning on the PI4. I suspect its receiving power from the ODB2 Port via the USB A port. Even thou the documentation states you cannot power the PI from the USB A ports.

If I physically unplug the cable from the charger or the ODB2 port that PI looses power.

Is it possible to avoid this happening and would it cause any problems if I run the setup like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with these Raspberry Pis.  The standard fix to this is to cut the 5V line in the cable.

If you don't want to alter or damage the cable, you can buy a USB extension cable and cut the 5 V wire in that.

I have also seen solutions where they simply place a small piece of electrical tape over the 5 V contact on the USB port before plugging in the cable.

Alternatively, you could place a Schottky diode on the 5 V line, allowing the Pi to power the USB peripheral but not allow back-feeding.